# Is there any way to exclude certain Maven artifacts when deploying to Artifactory with JFrog CLI?

Tags: java, maven, jar, artifactory, jfrog-cli

I'm trying to automate a Gitlab CI/CD pipeline for building and deploying a multi-module Maven project to Artifactory. I came across the JFrog CLI tool, but I have an issue due to the fact that there are some jars in my projects that have to be excluded from deployment.

The command I execute is something like this:

```
./jfrog rt mvn "clean install pom.xml" configuration.yml --build-name="something" --build-number="something"
```

In the documentation I cannot see any "--exclusions" parameter that I can configure.

How can I can configure an exclude pattern the same way I can with Jenkins Artifactory Plugin?
[Jenkins Artifactory plugin - exclude patterns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NgsD.jpg)

Comment: I don't think this is something that `jfrog` concerns with, you somehow need to exclude them with maven - you could create tow artifacts, one to be deployed and one not.

Comment: Why do you use the jfrog cli instead of just `mvn clean deploy`?

Comment: @JFabianMeier with mvn clean deploy deployment is done after each module and I don't want that. Also, with jfrog cli it's much faster and does not involve modifying the pom.xml files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is not yet officially supported in the JFrog CLI.

However, as a workaround, you can provide the `artifactory.publish.excludePatterns` Java property with a comma-separated list of excluded paths:

```sh
jfrog rt mvn clean install -Dartifactory.publish.excludePatterns="exclude-pattern-1,exclude-pattern-2"

# Example:
jfrog rt mvn clean install -Dartifactory.publish.excludePatterns="*artifact1*,*artifact2*"
```

You may expect to see the following prints in the logs:

> [main] INFO org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoRecorder - 'your-excluded-artifact-name' will not be deployed due to the defined include-exclude patterns.